Consulta con varios parametros en sqlite desde Python e insercion en Treeview
Consulta Sqlite3 en python devuelve una lista con varios valores pero longitud 1 que no puedo mostrar por índices Leyendo este post, me encuentro con dudas, necesito realizar una consulta a la BBDD con varios parámetros, el usuario no va a ingresar todos los parámetros de búsqueda, unicamente va a completar el campo que sea de su interés,los datos a ingresar para realizar la búsqueda son DNI, numero de Registro, dirección, entre otros, con una consulta "regular" puedo buscar y acomodar los datos sin ningún inconveniente, con una consulta común, y utilizando esta función le paso la consulta,
    `with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
        conn.commit()
    return result`

Luego, cuando le agrego los demas parametros para ingresar datos y luego realizar la busqueda, obtengo este resultado <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x772fd4e067c0> y no se inserta nada en el treeview.
query = """SELECT * FROM Tabla WHERE Numero = ? OR DNI = ? OR Dominio = ? OR Apellido = ? OR Calle = ? OR Seccion = ? OR Manzana = ? OR Parcela = ? """

param = (num, dni, dominio, apellido, calle, seccion, manzana, parcela)
db_rows = self.run_query(query, param)
print(db_rows)
for row in db_rows:
    self.tabla.insert('', 0, text = [1], values = row[1:31])

digamos que de esta manera y si utilizo solamente dos parámetros, funciona perfecto, al agregar mas parámetros se comporta como lo describí mas arriba.
Alguna idea de lo que puedo estar haciendo mal?

Finalmente lo conseguí, utilizando SQLSERVER, que es la base de datos que voy a utilizar en el proyecto final. Lo que hice fue definir un Combobox con las columnas a buscar. De esa lista desplegable selecciono el valor de mi interés, luego en un Entry escribo el valor que voy a buscar y finalmente en la función de búsqueda, con una declaración condicional definí varios if, uno para cada valor del Combobox y seguidamente una consulta en la base de datos para cada caso.

Lo que pasa, es que estás retornando el cursor directamente con return result y luego intentando iterar sobre él sin haber extraído los datos.
El cursor por sí mismo no contiene los resultados, sino un iterador que necesita usarse con métodos fetchall() o fetchone() para obtener las filas.
Para este problema, debes usar fetchall() antes de retornar el resultado de tu función.
with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
    rows = result.fetchall()  # Acá extraemos las filas
    conn.commit()
return rows # Retornamos las filas

Y luego, cuando agregas lo parámetros
db_rows = self.run_query(query, parameters)

# Iterar sobre las filas
for row in db_rows:
    print(row)

Si el problema fuera de parámetros como piensas, el error te lo diría.

De esta manera funciona correctamente, ya lo he probado, pero no inserta los valores en el treeview, unicamente puedo ver los resultados en la consola usando print. He probado con fetchone tambien y dependiendo las modificaciones que haga en la consulta, inserta pero no con los valores en cada campo, sino que toma todos los valores como un solo valor de lista e inserta las letras de las palabras en cada columna.

Entonces tienes un problema diferente al del cursor ahora ?? Que error te manda ahora?

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.12/tkinter/init.py", line 1967, in call
return self.func(*args)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/victor/Escritorio/Proyecto/Mesa_Entrada/Carga_Nuevo_Dato.py", line 566, in buscar_registro
self.tabla.insert('', 0, text = [1], values = row[1:31])
~~~^^^^^^
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
si bien en la consola imprime los valores, arroja este error

Ok, eso debe ser el insert que estas haciendo en el for entonces. Completa esta pregunta, dado que el problema del cursor esta corregido. Para ello dale al tick para marcar la respuesta correcta, y +1 que me ayudas a mi. Luego, has una nueva pregunta, describiendo el nuevo error, pero creo que lo puedes solucionar, dado que es solo corregir la linea dentro del for. Imprime la fila, y verifica los valores cuando te da el error.
